# how to add dataframe with one stacked column to a bigger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the main dataframe now looks like this
[the main dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o3yL.png)
[the main dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl1rP.png)
and i want to make it this  way
[new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVmzE.png)
[new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4NZ0.png)

Comment: could you provide an example of your data as a pd.DataFrame please, so we can reproduce the result

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please. Add your code you have as text to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks as though you are effectively trying to set the index as all the columns except the "genres_adj" column, so that all other columns only appear once.  Is that correct?  Otherwise, are you trying to convert the "genre_adj" column to a list in one line?  As above, please write the your question more specifically so others can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: It looks as though you are effectively trying to set the index as all the columns except the "genres_adj" column, so that all other columns only appear once.-->true

Comment: that's true because if i didn't  they gonna duplicate the other columns